# How to use QFontMetrics boundingRect to measure size of multilne message?

Tags: qt

I want to implement a a QGraphicsElement that draws text "as is" inside a rounded rectangle.

In order to implement QGraphicsElement I need to implement the boundedRect function, so I need the boundedRect for the multiline message as is.

As I understand it this is the function that I need to use http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfontmetrics.html#boundingRect-6 because it says it will treat newline chararcters as line breaks.

Now my question is this, If the information I want to know is the boundedRect of the text, how come I need to pass the boundedRect as a parameter?

Can anyone give me an example of how to get the boundedRect of a multiline QString? Or do I need to manually count the linebreaks and muliply that by the a single line height?

EDIT:

As arhzu shows the QRect passed as a parameter is used to define how the multiline text is contained. However, this is not usefull. As I want the witdth of said bounding box to be such that no word wrap is used. This should simply be the width of the longest string. So, I again ask is there anyway to obtain this? Or should I split the string by newline characters and then simply add the heights and the use the maximum width found?

Comment: When the word wrap flag is not used, the layout constraint is not used and the returned bounding rectangle should be the "as is" bounds for the input text. I updated my answer to print out the non-wrapped case, too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `rect` argument for `QFontMetrics::boundingRect` constrains the layout of the input text. You can use `Qt::TextWordWrap` flag to wrap long lines to multiple rows within the constraint rect. Here's an example where the allowed width of the text is varied:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QFontMetrics>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QFontMetrics fm = a.fontMetrics();

    QString text = QLatin1String("Multiline text string\n"
                                 "containing both long lines and line breaks\n"
                                 "to\n"
                                 "demonstrate bounding rect calculation");

    QList<int> widths = QList<int>() << 100 << 200 << 1000;
    foreach(int width, widths) {
        qDebug() << "With word wrapping:" << fm.boundingRect(QRect(0,0,width,100), Qt::TextWordWrap, text);
    }

    foreach(int width, widths) {
        qDebug() << "No wrapping" << fm.boundingRect(QRect(0,0,width,100), 0, text);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Running it on my system prints

```
With word wrapping: QRect(0,0 87x144)
With word wrapping: QRect(0,0 194x96)
With word wrapping: QRect(0,0 236x64)
No wrapping QRect(0,0 236x64)
No wrapping QRect(0,0 236x64)
No wrapping QRect(0,0 236x64)
```

EDIT: Added bounding rectangle calculation without word wrapping. The bounding rect argument is not used for anything in that case, it seems.

Comment: Ok. Now that I understand it better I need to reformulate the question. But thank you very much, while your answer was not what I was looking for, it did help me.

Comment: I have tired doing this. As I understand it, the value of width might as well be zero in your second for each. However the height of the returning bounding box is such that the text does not fit in it. However it does answer the question, but I still went with the manual solution.

Comment: No problem. If I add a `QLabel label; label.setText(text); label.show(); qDebug() << label.rect();` it prints exactly the same rect as for the font metrics. Maybe if you could provide some test data to see if it is a bug somewhere in Qt even?

Comment: Actually the system did not let me fixed my comment. I worked perfectly. The problem was something else .. jajaja. Thanks.